# How can I run a function when an App Engine Datastore record is created?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Using Python/Django on App Engine, is it possible for the creation of a Datastore record to cause a function to run?

I have more than one function that creates a record.  What I want is for every time any function creates a record of a certain Model, another function is run, without the function needing to be called from the code that originally created the record.